# Cmake managed C++

Tags: c++, cmake, managed

I have cli wrapper function which i am trying to configure in cmake. After i generate the project with cmake the generated .proj file does not have the property of clr support is set to no common languaage runtime support. below is my cmake file

```
    # This is the root ITK CMakeLists file.
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
    if(COMMAND CMAKE_POLICY)
     cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
    endif()

    set_target_properties(${TargetName} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/clr")
    SET(LINK_LIBRARIES
       D:\\2016\\RandomSlicing\\Processing\\lib\\obliquePlane.lib
    )
    # The header files
    SET(HEADERS
     ObliquePlaneWrapper.h
    obliquePlane.h
    )

 # The implementation files
  SET(SOURCES
   ObliquePlaneWrapper.cpp
  )

 # Find ITK.
 find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
 include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

 # Add this as include directory
 INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
   ${SOURCE_PATH}
   ${VXL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 )

 # Main library
 #ADD_EXECUTABLE(obliquePlane ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
 ADD_LIBRARY(ObliquePlaneWrapper SHARED  ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
 TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ObliquePlaneWrapper ${LINK_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

I manually set this property in the All_build project and the corresponding .proj file. When i build the project it is searching for the ObliquePlaneWrapper.dll which it should be generating. Is this a problem because of some flag not set for common language runtime support

Answer (score 2):

You can manually supply Compile Flags to specific sources to be compiled with specific flags. This includes \CLR for Visual C++. See example here.

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-April/043773.html